# Install PHP 7.4 met with "unmet dependencies", how to solve this?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-20.04, php-7.4

I know a lot of topics have the same question but I've tried everything and nothing works for me.
So I'm trying to install php 7.4 on my ubuntu stretch. I've done the following commands I found on the Internet:

```
apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https wget gnupg
wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt update
apt install php7.4
```

And then I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.4 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.4-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.4-cgi but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: php7.4-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I saw that someone followed the error by trying to install the depedencies that were causing the problem. So I then did

```
apt install php7.4-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-common : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I saw somewhere that it could be something in my /etc/apt/sources.list so here it is:

```
# Generated by distrobuilder
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

I'm stuck, I don't see what's wrong. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: Hello @Akame14, were you abale to fix this issue?

Answer (score 9):

please try below commands for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the incorrect distribution source list is referenced.

This can be resolved by resetting the source list of your Ubuntu distribution. The default list of Ubuntu 20.04 can be found at:

https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170

Replace the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the content above.

Then issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```